# Referencing not-yet-defined variables - Java

Tags: java

Because I'm tired of solving math problems, I decided to try something more engaging with my very rusty (and even without the rust, very basic) Java skills.  I landed on a super-simple people simulator, and thus far have been having a grand time working through the various steps of getting it to function.  Currently, it generates an array of people-class objects and runs a for loop to cycle through a set of actions that alter the relationships between them, which I have stored in a 2d integer array.  When it ends, I go look at how much they all hate each other.  Fun stuff.

Trouble has arisen, however, because I would like the program to clearly print what action is happening when it happens.  I thought the best way to do this would be to add a string, description, to my "action" class (which stores variables for the actor, reactor, and the amount the relationship changes).  This works to a degree, in that I can print a generic message ("A fight has occurred!") with no problem.  However, ideally I would like it to be a little more specific ("Person A has thrown a rock at Person B's head!").  This latter goal is proving more difficult: attempting to construct an action with a description string that references actor and reactor gets me a big old error, "Cannot reference field before it is defined."  Which makes perfect sense.

I believe I'm not quite in programmer mode, because the only other way I can think to do this is an unwieldy switch statement that negates the need for each action to have its own nicely-packaged description.  And there must be a neater way.  I am not looking for examples of code, only a push in the direction of the right concept to handle this.

Comment: Your question is too long. Make it more to-the-point.

Comment: Have you played with the order of declarations within your class?  What parameters are you passing into your Action.

Comment: Please show us the context in which you're getting the error.  I suspect you're simply defining local variables too late in the block, but it's hard to say without some context.

Comment: Could you link us to what simulator this is? Context would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. Quite a large wall of text. Hence:

## Breakdown

### Your setup

> Currently, it generates an array of people-class objects and runs a for loop to cycle through a set of actions that alter the relationships between them, which I have stored in a 2d integer array.
>
> I would like the program to clearly print what action is happening when it happens.
>
> I thought the best way to do this would be to add a string description to my "action" class (which stores variables for the actor, reactor, and the amount the relationship changes).

It sounds like your `Action` class so far looks something like this:

```
public class Action {
    private String reactor;
    private String actor;
    private double hateMeasure;
    /* Obligatory constructor method, getters, and setters go here */
}
```

### Your trouble

> I would like it to be a little more specific ("Person A has thrown a rock at Person B's head!").
>
> ... attempting to construct an action with a description string that references actor and reactor gets me ... "Cannot reference field before it is defined."

At this point I'm not quite sure how you're setting up your reference fields, and exactly how you're running into this error.

**I know you weren't looking for code, but you must appreciate the difficulty of getting somebody into "programmer mode" without showing them some skeletal principle-illustrating code.**

Perhaps create a method that takes two parameters of the actor and reactor, and then call that method after each action happens?

```
public void reportAction(String reactor, String actor) {
    // do stuff
} 
/* if you're confused by how "reactor" and "actor" have the same names as 
   the instance variables, look into the "this" keyword */
```

Alternatively (if your setup was different from what I inferred from your description, add in those instance variables and then) you can simply write a new method in your `Action` class that takes no parameters and simply references your instance variables:

```
public void reportAction() {
    System.out.println(actor + " with " + reactor);
}
```

Now it occurs to me that you may wish to specify *what* happened between the reactor and actor instead of simply stating that something happened between two specific simulated people. In that case...

```
public void reportAction() {
    System.out.print(actor);
    // you're going to have to define the change in hateMeasure here
    if( deltaHateMeasure > 0 ) { 
        System.out.print(" had a fight with " + reactor);
    } else { /* print other stuff */ }
}
```

Another fun thing for you to look at would be ternary operators, if you'd like to code this succinctly.

Have fun!

EDIT:

Even better!
Add in a `String descriptor;` instance variable to your class!

Then it all comes down to...:

```
public void reportAction() {
    System.out.println(actor + descriptor + reactor);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how you wrote your classes. Am I correct in assuming that at the time that you want to print your string, you do know the names of the actor and reactor?

If so, you should be able to do something along these lines:

```
System.out.printf(action.description, actor.name, reactor.name);
```

In which case action.description (or wherever you store your description string) looks something like:

```
"%s has thrown a rock at %s's head!";
```

I hope this helps!